# Why doesn't (use-package dired) work for me?

Tags: dired, use-package

`(use-package dired)` complains:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Package ‘dired-’ is unavailable")
```

But I see others' emacs configurations do use `(use-package dired)`, for example:

https://github.com/lunaryorn/.emacs.d/blob/088ac57/init.el#L829

https://github.com/bbatsov/emacs.d/blob/d94a751b/init.el#L295

https://github.com/mattss/emacs.d/blob/4e3cb1f5/init.el#L113

What's needed to make dired use-package-able?  Is this something to do with cask?

Comment: Have you set `use-package-always-ensure`?

Comment: Yes!  And `:ensure nil` stops it complaining.  Thank you, why not add that as an answer?

Comment: By the way, I guess the fact that the argument is `dired` means little here, in that case, and it's just functioning as a label... correct?

Comment: It's one example of a non-`package.el` "package", see my answer.

Comment: In 2019, do `use-package` and `use-package-always-ensure` still exist in the latest Emacs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ```
> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Package ‘dired-’ is unavailable")
> ```

You get this error when `package.el` tries to install a non-existent package.  `use-package` will attempt to install the given package name if you pass or `:ensure t` or you have set `use-package-always-ensure` to non-nil.  Use `:ensure nil` to override `use-package-always-ensure`.  You need to do this for any non-`package.el` package (of which `dired` is one example) that you `use-package` with.